# Pluralization of Latin words

Tags: grammar, plural, foreign-words

Is the pluralization of Latin words accepted or even correct, unlike the pluralization of those coming from other languages?

For example, "*sono stato in due bars*" would sound odd in Italian, but it's quite common to hear someone correcting somebody else for saying "*i curriculum*" instead of "*i curricula*" (the correct Latin pluralization for this noun).

Is this addressed by any linguistic reference? Is it more of a cultural issue instead?

Comment: Very related question on EL&U http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9004/which-style-of-latin-plurals-should-i-use

Comment: Great question, I wanted to ask this too!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, pluralization of the Latin words, as well as any other foreign words is generally not accepted in Italian (e.g., memorandum, referendum). *Il curriculum/i curricula* makes a famous exception (see [Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/plurale-curriculum)); though, there are some modern dictionaries that suggest *i curriculum*.

From La Grammatica Italiana di Dardano e Trifone (Zanichelli, 1995, p. 194):

> «Le grammatiche e i dizionari sono abbastanza compatti nel consigliare
>   il mantenimento della forma del singolare anche al plurale».
>   The
>   grammar rules and dictionaries unitedly recommend keeping the singular
>   form also as plural.

Italiano di Serianni (Garzanti, 1997, p. 106):

> «In che modo formano il plurale i nomi stranieri terminanti in
>   consonante? In generale, il nome resta invariato»
>   What is a plural
>   form of the foreign words ending with a consonant? Generally speaking,
>   the word remains unchanged.

Italiano, Corso di sopravvivenza di Birattari (Ponte alle Grazie, 2000, p. 250):

> Vale per le parole latine quel che si è detto per le parole straniere
>   in generale: in italiano sono invariabili. Quindi il plurale di
>   curriculum è i curriculum.
>   What is said above is valid for the Latin words in the same way as for other foreign words: in Italian, they don't change. Thus, the plural form of curriculum is i curriculum.

Comment: There is also a slightly confusing comment about it in Enciclopedia dell'Italiano (2011): "Quanto ai latinismi, è buona norma formare i loro plurali secondo le norme morfologiche latine: _curriculum → curricula, lectio magistralis → lectiones magistrales_, a meno che non si tratti di latinismi moderni, che restano invariati: _gli album, i referendum, gli sponsor_." I didn't include it in the answer because a) I can think of very few examples of such a "good practice"; b) I can't think of "sponsor" as a Latin word, even as a modern Latin word.